# How to capture query per seconds or microservice call latency? (without istio or other envoy based tool)

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, prometheus, istio, istio-kiali

Is there any way to capture metrics like query per seconds or latency of service call (between two services) in kubernetes environment without tool like Istio or any other enovy/mesh based architecture?

In other words, what are the metrics that are only possible by implementing a service mesh?

Comment: that's just a tertiary meah feature; the observability. You can imstall Prometheus for these metrics. Or Opentracing Api for telemetry.

Comment: @suren I believe these are metrics and not tracing features. Prometheus can only capture these metrics, but someone has to publish them.

Comment: service call latency can easily be Tracing. Prometheus has the agent, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Without a service mesh or proxy-based architecture, I would say it is up to your application to provide these metrics. There are prometheus exporters or modules for many popular frameworks. E.g. microprofile metrics, micrometer.io, etc. But envoy or service meshes would make it framework-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, makes sense to me. If you can put it in answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as a community wiki answer for better visibility.

as @Joel mentioned in comments.

> Without a service mesh or proxy-based architecture, I would say it is up to your application to provide these metrics. There are [prometheus exporters](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) or modules for many popular frameworks. E.g. [microprofile metrics](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-metrics), [micrometer.io](http://micrometer.io/), etc. But [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/) or [service meshes](https://istio.io/) would make it framework-agnostic.